# Can I pass an Array around into multiple Classes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object, oop

I am at currently navigating my way around OOP architecture and looking for best practices rather than code that just works. To highlight my latest conondrum I have written a short example of a problem I run into regularly below. In this example app users can start a learning journey of a programming subject they want to learn and plot their progress throughout. In reality I would need a backend for this type of app as the data will need to be saved, but for learning purposes I have written a short piece of code as if I am making it solely on the frontend.

A user can start a new learning journey by typing in the name of a journey and selecting the subject e.g. react, java, npm etc. This journey is then stored in an array of objects. Inside the app we can do a lot of things. e.g find all the React journeys by filtering, sort the journeys in various ways e.g. date started, add to an existing journey with text, highlight important words in the journey using the selection API in the browser.

I have written some code below which is a small snippet of what the app can do:

```
class Journey {
  constructor(name, subject, dateStarted = new Date().toLocaleString()) {
    this.name = name;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.dateStarted = dateStarted;
  }
}

class JourneyCollection {
  constructor(journeyArr = []) {
    this.journeysArr = journeyArr;
  }

  addJourney(name, subject) {
    this.journeysArr.push(new Journey(name, subject));
  }

  sortJourneys() { // as the app grows this will receive an argument to establish how we will sort e.g. by date, alphabetic, or number of updates to journey
    this.journeysArr.sort((a, b) => {
      return new Date(b.dateStarted) - new Date(a.dateStarted);
    });
  }

  getJourneysBySubject(subject) {
    const journeys = this.journeysArr.filter((jrny) => {
      return jrny.subject === subject;
  });

    return journeys;
  }
}

const journeys = new JourneyCollection();

document.querySelector("#add").addEventListener("click", () => {
  journeys.addJourney(
    document.querySelector("#name").value,
    document.querySelector("#subject").value
  );
});

document.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => { // if we hit enter the array gets sorted
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    journeys.sortJourneys();
  }
});

document.querySelector("#findSubject").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const returned = journeys.getJourneysBySubject(
    document.querySelector("#find").value
  );
});
```

Now the problem I am starting to have and will continue to have is that I am well on my way to having a god type class which controls the whole application because each method relies on the array which holds the all the Journeys.

Instead I was thinking of doing something where I can pass the array in each time as an argument and make several classes depending on what I want each part of the app to do. Taking just the part where I wan to add a journey, I thought of something like this:

```
const arrayOfJourneys = [];

class Journey {
  constructor(name, subject, dateStarted = new Date().toLocaleString()) {
    this.name = name;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.dateStarted = dateStarted;
  }
}

class AddJourney {
  constructor(arr, name, subject) {
    this.arr = arr;
    this.journey = new Journey(name, subject);
  }

  addJourney() {
    this.arr.push(this.journey);
  }
}

document.querySelector("#add").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const add = new AddJourney(
    arrayOfJourneys,
    document.querySelector("#name").value,
    document.querySelector("#subject").value
  );

  add.addJourney();
});
```

The pros and cons I can see so far

1. code1 Class will become too big and a lot of the Classes don't actually interact with each other or relate to each other, they all just need the journeys array inside the object created through the Class. I have read about God classes controlling apps and am not keen on this style.
2. code2 looks similar to an anti pattern I have read about called the Anemic Domain pattern where our classes just contain data. (in this case the array being the Data) although its not in a class it could be and I could call a method which returns it each time. Although reading into it I dont think my code2 above quite fits the Anemic criteria but it has frightened me. I like how I can change the state of this Array inside any other Class If I pass it in.
3. Code 2 whilst I think is better , my classes will all be verbs such as AddJourney or AddToExistingJourney or sortJourney. I have also read Classes should be Nouns and its behaviours should be the Verbs. I am not sure how important this is.

Perhaps there is another way that I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Those are good considerations. Your question may be a bit big for Stack Overflow. I admit I for my part didn’t read the whole way through it.

Comment: Maybe so, but its only fair I mention the research I have already conducted , the code I have written and my thinking as that constitutes a good question here rather than just state what my problem is and hope someone answers it.

Comment: @bergi knows everything, can you assist ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "*a lot of the Classes don't actually interact with each other or relate to each other, they all just need the journeys array*". There is only so much you can do with the array of journeys stored in your application (or possibly, also an array of journeys currently shown). Having all these methods go inside a single class doesn't seem wrong.

Comment: "*my classes will all be verbs such as AddJourney or AddToExistingJourney or sortJourney*" - yes, that is a problem. Or more, that all of these classes will have only a single method. In that case, you should just not use `class`es any more - write a plain `function`. This would become functional programming or procedural programming though, not object-oriented programming.

Comment: Thanks. So making a class that just returns an array and then passing that array around as a parameter to all other classes such as Add , Sort is not a good option? The best way in this situation would simple to have one big class with various methods all changing the state of the array or sorting it/returning filters from it?

Comment: I guess what I meant by not interacting with each other is that none of the methods have a parameter which is dependant on the result of another method. Each method can exist solely without the use of any other method that comes before or after it. A poor way of wording it I guess. 

It just feels wrong to have 20 methods that are all solely independent of each other in the same class because they rely on the same array, when I could just pass that array around to other classes as a parameter and thin down my classes?

Comment: When I first saw your code, I was wondering whether you were (perhaps unknowingly) trying to implement the Command design pattern. Look it up if you’re curious.Unless you have a specific need, you probably should not do that. This means, I agree with @Bergi to prefer methods over classes as long as they suffice.

Comment: "*The best way would be to have one big class with various methods all changing the state of the array or sorting it/returning filters from it?*" - yes. Since that is what these methods have in common: they're all changing the state of the same array. This is why they belong to the same class according to OOP principles. That they don't call each other doesn't matter.

Comment: The filtering methods that actually do not change the state, just return a view on it, could be separated out, e.g. using a `getFilteredJourneys` method that takes the filter predicate as an argument. Whether this is useful or not depends on how related/unrelated those predicates are, where they are used respectively, and how often each is used.

Comment: Marvellous. This clears everything up for me. I’m trying to establish OOP principles before looking into design patterns. Great help. Thanks

Comment: If you don't mind me adding 2 cents: manipulating common data by separate objects is what happens in many websites and even games. It's often solved by having a globally available data store that can easily be reached from any class. This prevents your classes from becoming too dependent on each other. In OOP you could use a Singleton class for this purpose.

Comment: @kokodoko isn’t that the opposite of the advice above ? That was my original architecture. I had a global array and was passing it into all other classes and changing if the state or filtering/sorting from that global Array. Bergi has advised against that and states OOP principles would suggest I put all methods into one class if each method is accessing the same Array. 

Would the singleton class be the class that holds the array in which all other classes can access? 

Have you just described the Anemic Domain Pattern there which I have read is not ideal?

Comment: I know from my React and Games experience that a single class that holds all your globally needed data (the "single source of truth") is a reliable way to work. Passing references around classes makes the hierarchy too rigid (hard to change afterwards). A singleton or just a class with static methods can be easy to reach from any point in your app. But yes, some devs with more experience than me say that the singleton or static methods are not "true oop".

Comment: @Kokodoko The global store of React applications isn't exactly OOP, especially if you use redux that's more like the ELM architecture. And you rarely use `class`es there afaict, it's all plain objects for the data and separate functions to manipulate them.

Comment: @Bergi That's correct, I used the analogy just to point out that a single place that holds all your data - and can be reached from anywhere - is a convenient way to work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very much dislike code #2.  I don't like that it takes raw data as an argument rather than taking another class/interface (which would be dependency injection).  I really don't like that it mutates the variable which is passed into the constructor by calling `push` on the `arrayOfJourneys`.

I'm also seeing issues with your `keypress` handler.  This calls a `journeys.sortJourneys()` method which mutates the array of journeys, but will it cause your UI to display them in the new order? Probably not.

> my classes will all be verbs such as AddJourney or AddToExistingJourney or sortJourney. I have also read Classes should be Nouns and its behaviours should be the Verbs. I am not sure how important this is.

I would not break this convention.  If adding a new journey involves a lot of logic then you could consider a `JourneyCreator` class.  But `AddJourney` is not a good class.

---

#### Mimicking backend code on the front-end

When I am designing front-end code that is a placeholder for backend code I like to mimic the sort of functionality that I would expect to eventually have in the backend.  I would create a `FakeDb` class with methods `getJourneyById`, `getJourneysList`, `addNewJourney`, `updateJourney`, etc.  When you think about it in those terms it might become more clear where to put certain logic.

Your goal is to design this is a way where swapping out your front-end data storage for backend storage involves changing as few pieces as possible.  You can have a `FakeDb` and a `RealDbWrapper` that conform to the same interface, and simply substitute one for the other.

Here's an example of how a stand-in for an API might look.  I'm using lodash [`orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy) which is a super helpful function for sorting arrays of objects.

I first wrote this TypeScript, React-safe (no mutations) version because that's what I normally write:

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import { keyBy, orderBy, omit } from 'lodash';

interface DbAddedFields {
    _id: string;
    dateCreated: string;
    dateModified: string;
}

interface JourneyUpdate {
    text: string;
    date: string;
}

interface JourneyData {
    name: string;
    subject: string;
    description?: string;
    updates: JourneyUpdate[];
}

type DbVersion<T> = T & DbAddedFields;
type NonDbVersion<T> = Omit<T, keyof DbAddedFields>;

class FakeDbTable<Datum> {
    private ids: string[] = [];
    private itemsById: Record<string, DbVersion<Datum>> = {};

    constructor(items: DbVersion<Datum>[] = []) {
        this.ids = items.map(item => item._id);
        this.itemsById = keyBy(items, '_id');
    }
    getIds(): string[] {
        return this.ids;
    }
    getById(id: string): DbVersion<Datum> {
        return this.itemsById[id];
    }
    getList(): DbVersion<Datum>[] {
        return this.getIds().map(id => this.getById(id));
    }
    add(item: Datum): DbVersion<Datum> {
        const _id = nanoid();
        const dateCreated = new Date().toLocaleString();
        const dbVersion: DbVersion<Datum> = {
            ...item,
            _id,
            dateCreated,
            dateModified: dateCreated
        }
        this.ids = this.getIds().concat(_id);
        this.itemsById = {
            ...this.itemsById,
            [_id]: dbVersion
        };
        return dbVersion;
    }
    delete(id: string): void {
        this.ids = this.getIds().filter(itemId => itemId !== id);
        this.itemsById = omit(this.itemsById, id);
    }
    update(id: string, patch: Partial<Datum>): DbVersion<Datum> {
        const existing = this.getById(id);
        const merged = {
            ...existing,
            ...patch,
            dateModified: new Date().toLocaleString()
        };
        this.itemsById = {
            ...this.itemsById,
            [id]: merged
        };
        return merged;
    }
}

class JourneyCollection {
    private data: FakeDbTable<JourneyData>;

  constructor(journeyArr: DbVersion<JourneyData>[] = []) {
    this.data = new FakeDbTable<JourneyData>(journeyArr);
  }

  addJourney(name: string, subject: string) {
    this.data.add({ name, subject, updates: [], description: '' });
  }

  getSortedJourneys(field: keyof DbVersion<JourneyData>, order: 'desc' | 'asc') {
    return orderBy(this.data.getList(), field, order);
  }

  getJourneysBySubject(subject: string) {
    return this.data.getList().filter(journey => journey.subject === subject);
  }
}

const journeys = new JourneyCollection();
```

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgOwIbIsAJnAvnAMyghDgHI0NsyBuAKFElkTmiwFMoAhATz0OKkyAGwhZUAZwAWtOg2QxOBVAGN2cACIAjAIJYOWAGLB2wrBMR041uAH1sALjgSYUYMgDm9G3HGKAwlDsqIpYTi5unt42fuwAsmLABCZhzq7uXnS4cu6KUMpqcABSEACuUMjsPACqYLGWPooAHjDh6VFWMSHsbZGZ2fJ5Beol5ZU8GiGoDTZoID1pfdHWEqVaAFbsKq2LGcu%207BIqbmAwwBDIAPy9e53WpXXdEk6jFVW1sQDaALr0AzA8MDqbQANU4EnOyAAPAAVAB8cAAvHAYXAAGSaXT6dhGExmCT0AFAuAAOQuoPBkNhCORAHkQMAYLCADRwADWVQgBExegMxlM5jh9DoKmEkgshlQHO0MNQWmE7ChkxgpRACIQdzgYDcADdunBsM9dp4fki4D99trgHrFAbFCAJLwAJKpABKWzYUIiGVZFKgEIuSpCqrhNMQuGFPhUFwipW20AAFIz2A6nH6A9DlSHTcifgBKGY%20azJh0AOgI0AAoqopEn7Uj1ZqizYYFJgBJS4bS2BStI6ynS-YsHn9s3rK32537Y6eC7PiXB9hvmaS6ObLgR5rsj4POwYC6JAm8zcTcuNWO4EEVRU4BOO4b9tubLuYM6sEnUt7PMfMWD-VSszVQsiyvMZbzbe9pzfecsF%20LdNRfAAZdsYCPNMtD-DMgxVNVTXPMdQJvO9SxfA8j1LEBUDAD8G3AycXzfD8803Hwn2sVB9H7EA02DEAf3TADeMbC9o2QFw7GwM1KEwd8WLHUTxNiQJglCKT2AAd00bpyJgCBEIgFRUAVABldoPCPNdrAU%20AsAwykLnQzDBJwsN8IvaxS08ktmSbMchx89yugCIJuiwALAt8boEiwJIUicJSQtCXzrDYotiMNM1iNI8xyNEwzUKHOTm3SqDZywT4h2XZFbKci5LMvPcwJq%20zkEfTUOAVRQPxPDwfx1GTgMaCDO3MTLhuyw883LYBhDyLiXVoksFoAQkRZFsCKosOr3dQSpTGc5yXNqfAeWJuuNDxWTAEIVCkJwAAVUFgYAjOwkN%20Ls-9A0A4T5JjeB2CaFCMjG%20i90Yjb6usuB5igXccGRNz3M80tAeBzxwsClHrpgW7Mfc2JotinEnEqTTlXYHS9IMoz2FMvoj2SvB6r2h1oKXM1Yfh%20rCOQGHOG5%20CBlFcVijKN4eH8CBhAVbZIWAq0bXUPxUCcSVpS0WV5UVV5xmVVAhTkKz-qgONdKgBN1nF8YdCgKBHJaqFdaqfW4Rzc1vgLJHiJVtTNPV9gZTlBUnetl2pjhS2w54W2oDkgZ2P0Z2eATOYFi-S7nDWTZth6r3NR9qZSw498kDT1lVg2LYYFZU6nicH5WQ4I4TjOBzyDIPB46NuAX2M6BQmTw9kgFJwOR4Llf0d5PXdZNhOCcMhm5UTuAB9yEkFf858XnWCgDhuBTwuYFQEi92Qlwj1ZEezDn-fOG7zoXyH3hjOz6uE0rnOdgz7ebF34%20p8kIoXIskWanAo5jCqLRK2UCeCli-tXJEa0s5V22N3YW-04CwIlhYZEZMxZwKljLaukILJAA)

But I think this JS version is more how you were thinking:

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import { orderBy } from 'lodash';

class Journey {
    constructor(name, subject, dateCreated = new Date().toLocaleString()) {
        this.name = name;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.description = '';
        this.updates = [];
        this._id = nanoid();
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        this.dateModified = dateCreated;
    }

    private setModifiedDate() {
        this.dateModified = new Date().toLocaleString();
    }

    addUpdate(text) {
        this.updates.push({
            text,
            date: new Date().toLocaleString()
        });
        this.setModifiedDate();
    }
}

class JourneyCollection {
    constructor(journeys = []) {
        this.ids = [];
        this.itemsById = {};
        journeys.forEach(journey => {
            this.ids.push(journey._id);
            this.itemsById[journey._id] = journey;
        });
    }
    getIds() {
        return this.ids;
    }
    getById(id) {
        return this.itemsById[id];
    }
    getList() {
        return this.getIds().map(id => this.getById(id));
    }
    add(name, subject) {
        const journey = new Journey(name, subject);
        this.ids.push(journey._id);
        this.itemsById[journey._id] = journey;
        return journey;
    }
    delete(id) {
        this.ids = this.getIds().filter(itemId => itemId !== id);
        delete this.itemsById[id];
    }
    // Can update the items directly but modifying the Journey instance.
    getSortedList() {
        return orderBy(this.getList(), 'dateModified', 'desc');
    }
    getBySubject(subject) {
        return this.getList().filter(journey => journey.subject === subject);
    }
}

const journeys = new JourneyCollection();
```

Comment: I always want to mutate data held in one class by calling a method of another class and passing it in e.g I made a game on Monopoly, I wanted to pass in the current player to a chance method which does something to the player. E.g adds money 

I can pass the player into a chance method and mutate the instance of the player (created in another class) but has one memory reference but instead I find myself calling Methods from my player class such as player.changeMoney(chance.getMoney())  Instead of chance.changeMoney(player) to mutate the player. Why is the later deemed bad?

Comment: Good question.  I can't articulate this well, but sometimes it breaks encapsulation for one object to mutate another.  The player might have some side effect logic beyond just changing the value of a property.  Like "if money === 0, declare bankruptcy".  So it's better for your chance class to call a public method of the player object to set the money.  Some of my avoidance of mutations is just a habit from writing UIs in React (the UI changes when a variable changes, but it won't change if a variable is mutated).  But I don't know how you're generating the UI here.

Comment: Thanks. I’m using MVC. In the model I have a chance class and a player class. I call a method from the current chance, the current chance is always the node [0] of the chances array. E.g. Const amount = chance.changeMoney(). I will then pass amount into a method of the player object (which is equal to the current players turn) such as currentPlayer.changeMoney(‘+’, amount) which mutates the money directly inside my players class. Do you think this is the cleanest way? The UI is Dom methods rather than react where I pass in any changes to them player to a method of the Ui class.

Comment: Your breaking encapsulation comment is very helpful. I have called methods from other classes before but never to mutate them, mainly just to use or read them!! Would you think it’s fair to say mutating objects of one class from another could lead to buggy hard to fix code? Whereas if we encapuslate all mutations , then it’s easier to see where things go wrong ?

Comment: Yes, I agree with those statements.   What you are describing re: chance sounds good.  The chance object tells the player object "I am giving you x dollars" and it's up to the player class to actually increment the total.

Comment: You’ve been a great help. My architecture is slightly different to calling a method of the player object inside the chance object as youve described. I don’t call any player method from the chance object. I just called the chance method which returns a value to my controller module and then pass the value into my players object. Would you recommend that or shall I call the method from the player directly in the chance object meaning I I would still use a player method to mutate but from inside the chance object rather than the controller ? Which one do you think is best ?

Comment: No I think that doing it in the controller is probably better :)

Comment: @bergi Small update, When using OOP on the front end then surely my classes are specific.E.g class AddJourney will be a post to my Api which adds a journey to an obj or dbase? Class GetJourney will be a get req for a previously added journey? I get the backend has an array containing all the journeys with methods to control the state ready for frontend requests but When the client receives back JSON data to display to the user, then our classes on the frontend that fetch the data are surely verbs describing exactly what it is we want to do? How does this sound? Thanks

Comment: can you assist with the above Comment ? Thank you

Comment: hi Linda. I’m wondering if you could help. Your first paragraph string why you don’t like code 2. Let’s saw I create a class which holds this array with a single method that returns the array, I want this To use this array in multiple different other classes. In the other classes I am still changing or reading the internal objects of the array(by calling methods of the objects held in the array). E.g in monopoly I need this Array in my House class or Mortgage class. Otherwise if I can only use the array in one class, that class would be huge containing all the methods 1/2

Comment: of the game that target the players class. Meaning I’m in big violation of the SRP? How can I stick to SRP if I can only use that array in the class it’s defined in? Can’t I return it via a getter or inject the object that holds this array as a property of another class? This would really help me! I don’t intend to mutate the data in the Array by content coupling them from another class, but I do intend on reading the methods/changing the data inside the objects, strictly by calling methods from the object inside the Array!!

Comment: @bergi can you advise if possible?